# Using TwiML, how do I use <say> to response to user after dtmf inpu?

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I have a simple test application that makes a call, and using TwiML, it asks the user to press 1 or 2. Everything is working great. My action is called, I get by my POST response. The only thing that I would like to do is once the user selects 1 or 2, use  to thank them. Currently when entering 1 or 2, the call is just ended.

Here is my current TwiML...

```
<Response>
    <Gather action="doSomething" method="POST" timeout="5" numDigits="1" finishOnKey="#">
        <Say voice="woman">Press 1 or press 2</Say>
    </Gather>
    <Say voice="woman">You did not press anything, goodbye.</Say>
</Response>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

In the "doSomething", you would return TwiML, using `Say` Verb to thank them. When TwiML ends, the call ends.

Comment: Ahh! I see, this worked perfectly! Now I also see how I can tailor the response based on the the value selected! Thank you!